# JTable select all shifts rows

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I added the following code as a listener to JTableHeader:

```
        header.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            JTableHeader header = (JTableHeader) e.getSource();
            JTable table = header.getTable();
            TableColumnModel columnModel = table.getColumnModel();
            int vci = columnModel.getColumnIndexAtX(e.getX());
            int mci = table.convertColumnIndexToModel(vci);
            if (mci == targetColumnIndex) {
                TableColumn column = columnModel.getColumn(vci);
                Object v = column.getHeaderValue();
                boolean b = Status.DESELECTED.equals(v) ? true : false;
                TableModel m = table.getModel();
                for (int i = 0; i < m.getRowCount(); i++) m.setValueAt(b, i, mci);
                column.setHeaderValue(b ? Status.SELECTED : Status.DESELECTED);
                //header.repaint();
            }
        }
    });
```

If I manually select one of more cells, then If I click the ckeckAll header, this code executes and then the visual order of rows is changing, thos selected jump to the bottom/top. ANy ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `TableHeader`s in a `JTable` already have a built in listener on them that sorts the values based on the `Comparator` for the specific `Object` type stored in that column.

You are adding a second listener to that table instead of overwriting the built-in one. So you are seeing the effects of both actions.

**Update**

If you don't want any sorting capability, you can disable your row sorter, or just implement your own. You could also implement your own custom `TableColumn`s as well.

Comment: Can I somehow disable the initial, sorting one somehow? or if not, any other approach to stop sorting?

Comment: I've updated my answer, I haven't ever had to do this myself, but I am absolutely positive that its possible.